# Host closes connection

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcpclient

I have a very basic problem with the .NET TcpClient. I want to send 100 messages to a server with roughly 1ms cycle time.

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
  tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.1", 59917);

  var strm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    // Send string to server
    byte[] outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"Hello World{i}!");
    strm.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    strm.Flush();

    Thread.Sleep(1); // causes exception :-(
  }

  tcpclnt.Close();
}
```

After a few iterations (mostly 3) I will get an exception: "the host closed the connection". In my case the host is a simple TCP/UDP sender/receiver application called "PacketSender".

However if I remove the wait, the exception goes away. All 100 messages are transmitted:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
  tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.1", 59917);

  var strm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    // Send string to server
    byte[] outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"Hello World{i}!");
    strm.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    strm.Flush();
  }

  tcpclnt.Close();
}
```

How can I slow down the sending without running into the exception?
Am I using the TcpClient wrong?

Comment: Perhaps there is a timeout setting on the server side application that could be increased? On a side note, TcpClient.GetStream returns a NetworkStream. According to Microsoft's documentation, NetworkStream is not buffered. "The Flush method implements the Stream.Flush method; however, because NetworkStream is not buffered, it has no affect on network streams." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: 1ms seems very short to me. That should not trigger any timeout. Also: why would the client be required to continuously send data?

Comment: Sorry, I misread, some reason I thought it said 1 second.